# Trying to load a 6-month old FB group but get 'out of memory'

Tags: memory, browser, facebook

For research purposes (qualitative), I would like to load (see) all the posts of a 6-month Facebook group but after a few days of posts are loaded I get an 'out of memory' error and the web page or browser crashes.

I've tried Chrome, Opera and Firefox, but all experience the same problem. I've tried to load the page by a scrolldown add-on or simply putting an object on the End key and giving it time to load. When I reach posts from the beginning of October or around this time, the error occurs.

I intend to use another script that automatically expands all the comments and replies. It works fine with a few posts but with a lot of posts, I get the out of memory error.

My intention is to save the loaded page (all posts since the beginning) either as a HTML page or use an automatic scrolldown add-on and video screen record the whole group while the automatic scrolldown is working.

- I don't want to use a data scraper because I want the posts as they are (interested in cultural analysis)
- I have the consent of the people of the group and have taken care of the ethics side of research, so please don't discuss this
- This is running on Windows 10 Professional, i7-5500U, 2.40GHz, 8GB of RAM

How can I avoid the 'out of memory" error?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How high does your memory usage reach? Is this a web browser error or a Windows error?

Comment: I didn't take note of the memory usage, but it is a browser error, and the computer keeps its normal speed. The browser or webpage refreshes and I have to start all over gain.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error? Also provide a screenshot of the Console tab when you press F12. Provide screenshots of the task manager as well.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?